# Which flavor of latex to use? LuaTeX, XeLaTeX or LaTeX?

Tags: xetex, luatex

When I started using TeX, it was easy to build. Today I discovered that I can use different flavor of LaTeX to build my (La)TeX files. Is there a general rule of which flavor I should consider for a regular project (let say a letter to the Tax Office)?

With `inputenc` and `fontenc` I was able to use unicode so why should I consider XeLaTeX or LuaTeX instead?

Comment: There are several questions on the site about pdfTeX/XeTeX/LuaTeX or combinations thereof. There's no 'hard' rule as to which engine you should use, so if you are happy with a workflow then you should stick with it. (I use a combination of engines depending on my use case: for documents in English I'm quite happy with pdfTeX in most cases.)

Comment: @JosephWright It would be interesting to know your choices depending on your use cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Joseph said in the comments there are no fixed rules to decide on an engine. I tend to use `pdflatex` in most cases but switch to `xelatex` if I want to use an OpenType font that is not available for `pdflatex`.

An argument to **use `pdflatex`** might be that `microtype` has more power on that engine (as far as I know). While an argument **for `xelatex` (or `latex`)** is the native support of Unicode and the ability to use any font.

Comment: Good news, I did not know `otf` fonts are now supported. Bad news, `xelatex` is another engine to put on my list.